# Moving mysql data directory to different location

Tags: mysql

I created a mysql instance with "/Volumes/x" as data directory. I want to move this to "Volumes/y". But, this throws an error saying the mysql tables don't exist and database exists with fatal error.

Is there a way to move data directory to different location?

I get below errors, when I try to move the data directory. By the way, I updated the /etc/my.cnf with the location of the new path. Still I get these errors.

```
130219 19:26:33 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
130219 19:26:33 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
130219 19:26:33 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130219 19:26:33 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130219 19:26:33 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130219 19:26:33 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.0G
130219 19:26:33 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130219 19:26:33 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130219 19:26:33  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130219 19:26:34 InnoDB: 5.5.30 started; log sequence number 1593283
130219 19:26:34 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
130219 19:26:34 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130219 19:26:34 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Missing system table mysql.proxies_priv; please run mysql_upgrade to create it
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_current' has the wrong structure
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_history' has the wrong structure
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_history_long' has the wrong structure
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_consumers' has the wrong structure
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_instruments' has the wrong structure
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_timers' has the wrong structure
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'performance_timers' has the wrong structure
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'threads' has the wrong structure
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'mutex_instances' has the wrong structure
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'rwlock_instances' has the wrong structure
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'cond_instances' has the wrong structure
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_instances' has the wrong structure
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Column count of mysql.db is wrong. Expected 22, found 20. Created with MySQL 50091, now running 50530. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] mysql.user has no `Event_priv` column at position 29
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Cannot open mysql.event
130219 19:26:34 [ERROR] Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
130219 19:26:34 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.30'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

I ran mysql_upgrade, and below is the output and if I restart after that, there are no errors. I am still concerned why I am seeing errors at all.

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--datadir' option is always ignored
Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck' with connection arguments: '--port=3306' '--socket=/tmp/mysql.sock' 
Running 'mysqlcheck' with connection arguments: '--port=3306' '--socket=/tmp/mysql.sock' 
bala_test.bala_1                                   OK
bala_test.bala_2                                   OK
mysql.columns_priv                                 OK
mysql.db                                           OK
mysql.func                                         OK
mysql.help_category
error    : Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `help_category`" or dump/reload to fix it!
mysql.help_keyword
error    : Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `help_keyword`" or dump/reload to fix it!
mysql.help_relation                                OK
mysql.help_topic
error    : Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `help_topic`" or dump/reload to fix it!
mysql.host                                         OK
mysql.proc
error    : Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `proc`" or dump/reload to fix it!
mysql.procs_priv
error    : Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `procs_priv`" or dump/reload to fix it!
mysql.tables_priv                                  OK
mysql.time_zone                                    OK
mysql.time_zone_leap_second                        OK
mysql.time_zone_name
error    : Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `time_zone_name`" or dump/reload to fix it!
mysql.time_zone_transition                         OK
mysql.time_zone_transition_type                    OK
mysql.user                                         OK

Repairing tables
mysql.help_category                                OK
mysql.help_keyword                                 OK
mysql.help_topic                                   OK
mysql.proc                                         OK
mysql.procs_priv                                   OK
mysql.time_zone_name                               OK
Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'...
OK
```

Comment: RTLM? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir

Comment: Did you try running mysql_upgrade like it suggests?  The output above makes me think you left out some details of what you did.

Comment: mysqld_safe successfully starts the database, but mysqld doesn't work

Comment: Yes, I ran mysqld_upgrade. But, it is actually not necessary.

Comment: Actually running mysql_upgrade helps, as it creates the privilege tables again. I am worried if any data is lost.